# Risks of having SSH private key stolen

Tags: authentication, ssh

I'm afraid this is quite a common question, but searching several times through the questions did not prove useful, and I'm really eager of knowledge here :D

I understand that keeping SSH private key well secured (strong passphrase, backup ecc.) is crucial, but I'm wondering about how much having it stolen is dangerous. An eventual attacker, once got our private key, could log into every server which has our public key in *authorized_keys*, right? But besides that, are there other things that he could use the key for?

Comment: Isn't this bad enough?

Comment: Depends what else is the the key used for. Best place to store your key is a smartcard or something similar.

Comment: @M'vy sure that is bad, I was just curious :D

Comment: @mikky Can SSH private keys be used for something else?

Comment: Technically yes, why not. It's (usually) just an RSA key that can be used in any RSA-enabled application.

Comment: There are ways to sync OpenSSL and OpenSSH keys, so if you share your private key with your browser for SSL client cert access, that becomes vulnerable, but this is rather limited if we're talking about *client* keys. Server keys might be more dangerous, as you have third parties trusting them and it would allow an attacker to pose as your server in an MitM attack.

Answer (score 2):

Because even if you've secured your private key with a strong passphrase, the passphrase is the *only protection* of the key.

And since the encrypted key is only one part of an equation (your passphrase is the other half) it only needs enough computation power to bruteforce "crack" that key.

So, the key is as valuable as the passphrase to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try drawing a mitigation tree where you can visualize the effects of a compromised key on the service environment. Also, you might want to take into account the physical safety of the key itself.